# mysql services restarted automatically in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

Good day!

I am getting the followin error and everytime i get this  the sql service gets restarted automatically.
We tried changing the max_open_files and Limitnofile but still unlucky.

The error below:#

```
2021-02-24T05:48:23.615394Z 135 [Warning] [MY-010057] [Server] IP address '144.217.89.37' has been resolved to the host name '37.ip-144-217-89.net', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
05:55:13 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7fba5418e130
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fba64a5ed10 thread_stack 0xc0000
/usr/sbin/`mysqld`(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x55b2aaf1049d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x2fb) [0x55b2a9eba22b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12980) [0x7fbac2056980]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf293ce) [0x55b2a9d5d3ce]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf295f2) [0x55b2a9d5d5f2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf29623) [0x55b2a9d5d623]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::finalize_table_conditions()+0xeb) [0x55b2a9d6387b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::optimize()+0x2e16) [0x55b2a9d77866]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0xb6) [0x55b2a9dd3c46]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x7b) [0x55b2a9e423eb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0x115) [0x55b2a9dd3ca5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x7b) [0x55b2a9e423eb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute_inner(THD*)+0x3d) [0x55b2a9dd265d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x598) [0x55b2a9ddc6e8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xaae) [0x55b2a9d7f46e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_instr_stmt::exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*)+0x51) [0x55b2a9cfbe71]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::reset_lex_and_exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0x17b) [0x55b2a9cfdd4b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::validate_lex_and_execute_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0xde) [0x55b2a9cfecfe]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_instr_stmt::execute(THD*, unsigned int*)+0xc3) [0x55b2a9d00543]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_head::execute(THD*, bool)+0x3be) [0x55b2a9cf50de]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_head::execute_procedure(THD*, mem_root_deque<Item*>*)+0x7e3) [0x55b2a9cf8423]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_call::execute_inner(THD*)+0x136) [0x55b2aa20b106]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x598) [0x55b2a9ddc6e8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xaae) [0x55b2a9d7f46e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x3f9) [0x55b2a9d82d29]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x15ed) [0x55b2a9d8480d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x1c4) [0x55b2a9d85fe4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1077020) [0x55b2a9eab020]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2640091) [0x55b2ab474091]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7fbac204b6db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7fbac023d71f]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fba549617f8): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 28
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2021-02-24T05:55:13.760686Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010140] [Server] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 10000 (request: 25000)2021-02-24T05:55:13.760686Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010140] [Server] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 10000 (request: 25000)
2021-02-24T05:55:14.042554Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 31229
2021-02-24T05:55:14.054670Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-02-24T05:55:14.941930Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-02-24T05:55:15.232295Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-02-24T05:55:15.260938Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-02-24T05:55:15.273573Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-02-24T05:55:15.316036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-02-24T05:55:15.316219Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-02-24T05:55:15.344388Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-02-24T05:55:15.551426Z 8 [Warning] [MY-010057] [Server] IP address '167.114.185.61' has been resolved to the host name '61.ip-167-114-185.net', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
```

Anyone has anyidea. The current mysql version is 8.0.23 community version.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you could post the additional information requested Mar 4, 2021 someone will try to assist.